# Python - converting textfile contents into dictionary values/keys easily

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting, key

Let's say I have a text file with the following:

```
line = "this is line 1"
line2 = "this is the second line"
line3 = "here is another line"
line4 = "yet another line!"
```

And I want to quickly convert these into dictionary keys/values with " line* " being the key and the text in quotes as the value while also removing the equals sign.

What would be the best way to do this in Python?

Comment: Why do you want it as a dictionary, instead of using one of the many config file parsers that would understand this already?

Comment: which ones are those?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
f = open(filepath, 'r')
answer = {}
for line in f:
    k, v = line.strip().split('=')
    answer[k.strip()] = v.strip()

f.close()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

In one line:

```
d = dict((line.strip().split(' = ') for line in file(filename)))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    d = dict((line.strip().split(' = ') for line in file('F:\lines.txt')))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @jim, which version of Python?

Comment: For Python 3, I think you need to use: d = {line.strip().split(' = ') for line in file(filename)}, but I don't have Python 3, so I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the `urlopen` version of inspectorG4dget's answer might look like:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sedeh/github.io/master/resources/states.txt'
response = urlopen(url)
lines = response.readlines()
state_names_dict = {}
for line in lines:
    state_code, state_name = line.decode().split(":")
    state_names_dict[state_code.strip()] = state_name.strip()
```