# Convert list of strings into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to convert a list of strings into a dictionary.

The list looks like such after I have split it into the seperate words:

```
[['ice'], ['tea'], ['silver'], ['gold']]
```

Which I want to convert to a dictionary which looks like such:

```
{ 1 : ['i', 'c', 'e'] 
  2 : ['t','e','a']
  3 : ['s','i','l','v','e','r']
  4 : ['g','o','l','d']}
```

This is my code thus far:

```
import itertools

def anagram1(dict):
    with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()

        data = data.split()

        x = []

        y = []

        for word in data:
                x1 = word.split()
                x.append(x1)

        for letters in word:
            y1 = letters.split()
            y.append(y1)
            d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(y)] * 2, fillvalue=""))
```

To which I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: What have you done that didn't work ? Please show your effort, SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - converting textfile contents into dictionary values/keys easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942874/python-converting-textfile-contents-into-dictionary-values-keys-easily)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
l = [['ice'], ['tea'], ['silver'], ['gold']]
d = {idx: list(item[0]) for idx, item in enumerate(l, start =1)}
pprint.pprint(d)
```

> ```
> {1: ['i', 'c', 'e'],
>  2: ['t', 'e', 'a'],
>  3: ['s', 'i', 'l', 'v', 'e', 'r'],
>  4: ['g', 'o', 'l', 'd']}
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Following should do the job:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.split()

data_dict = {i:v for i,v in enumerate(data)}
```