# Can I convert a text file to python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, dataset

```
d = dict((line.strip().split(' = ') for line in file(filename)))
```

I used this code, but printed an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942874/python-converting-textfile-contents-into-dictionary-values-keys-easily .

Comment: pls provide the file content, and the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - converting textfile contents into dictionary values/keys easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942874/python-converting-textfile-contents-into-dictionary-values-keys-easily)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in your code.

Simply replace `file` with `open` like this:

```
d = dict((line.strip().split(' = ') for line in open(filename)))
```